# I need to sum up the number of times a range of strings appear

Tags: excel, vba

So I have some data imported from multiple databases. For one column a range of strings is imported and these strings do change. In another column on the spreadsheet they are imported to, I need a SUM of how many times EACH string has appeared in the imported list.

I already have the macro producing a unique string column so the sums can go next to that.

I was thinking about whether you can compare the imported list to the unique list and +1 in the specific cells each time each unique name appears and cycle through all unique list names?

EG:

```
Imported list                Unique List                        Sum
abc                          abc                                2 
cbc                          cbc                                1
aop                          aop                                1
aoz                          aoz                                1
abc                          xyz                                1
xyz
```

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Consider using ***COUNTIF()***

Comment: Or you can use a Pivot table to do it all, the unique list and the count.

Comment: I had used COUNTIF() already however I had not set the range to be unlimited. The length of the columns imported varies and its unknown whether it will be 100 rows one week to 10000 the next.   Although at the same time I used it in the cells rather than the VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A**, consider:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, C As Range
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set B = Range("B:B")

    A.Copy B
    B.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, "C").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(A, Cells(i, "B").Value)
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that! It's exactly what I was thinking in my head but couldn't actually do it. How would I offset the results so that it copies into column "C" without overwriting the heading?

Comment: @DaleSwire  Start with changing from the posted code to `i=2` .................other changes may be required............this is only demo code..................

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student. I had changed everything else to suit my code and it all worked perfectly. The only exception of course was that it started in the first row. Apologies for the rookie question, I've been racking my head around the first part so much I'm scrambled!